# What is meant by $f(x)$ is function of $x$. Or $f(x)$ as a function of $y$?

Tags: calculus

I am so confused about the terminology and vocabulary here. I tried googling it but couldn't find anything satisfactory. I have a test tomorrow. I would be glad if someone could explain what this conceptually means.

Comment: I don't think anyone can give a good answer in the answer box since "I am so confused" is not specific enough. I also do not know what f(x) as a function of y means.

Comment: $f(x)$ is a function of $x$ would be correct and it just means $f$ depends on $x$. Saying $f(x)$ is a function of $y$ would be wrong.

Comment: Do you want a full explanation of functional notation?
What resources did you find?
How about [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/test-prep/sat/new-sat-tips-planning/sat-math-test-lessons/a/gtp--sat-math--article--function-notation--lesson)?
How about [MathBitsNotebook](https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Algebra1/Functions/FNNotationEvaluation.html) ?
What is confusing you about the explanations you found?

Comment: It is not $f(x)$ which is a function of $x$, but $f$. $f(x)$ is the value of the function $f$ at $x$.

Comment: @ndhanson3 I disagree that "$f(x)$ is a function of $x$" is correct. That may be the usual phrase but it's not technically correct. One should simply say "$f$ is a function" and "$f(x)$ is the value of $f$ at $x$".

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz: "A function of $x$" is a quite common way to say "an expression in which the variable $x$ is free", and I don't see a particular reason to call it incorrect -- especially since I'm not aware of any _other_ common meaning of "a function of $x$".

Comment: @Troposphere, I think JackozeeHakkiuz was taking issue with the "$f(x)$" part, not the "is a function of $x$" part. The previous comments suggest that $f$ is a function and $f(x)$ is a value. I've always thought of $f(x)$ as being a term, not a value, which evaluates to a member of the codomain when $x$ is replaced by a member of the domain, but I'm sure I never phrased it that way when teaching calculus. I have probably called it a function, without worrying about the distinction.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're currently in high school so without beating around the bush and/or being pedantic and asking you for definitions (which is futile as it is obvious you have this question *because* you don't know your definitions in the first place) *and* since you have an exam coming up very soon, I'll give you a straight answer.

$f(x)$ simply means the output value **using the function** $f$ when $x$ is the input value. For example: $f(x)=2x+3$ then for input value $x=2$, the output value **using the function** $f$ is $f(2)=2(2)+3=7$. You'd usually (conventionally) want to plot these output values of function $f$ on $Y$ axis and input values on $X$ axis on a graph paper. So we set $y = f(x)$. And hence, now $y$ is simply another name for $f(x)$.